# How to create rules SonarQube in php project? For beginners dev

Tags: php, sonarqube, rules, manual

Need help, please write me some example custom rules sonarqube in php project. I want to use this tool, but I can't find the detailed manual. Thank you!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The best source of rule examples is [SonarPHP](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-php/tree/master/php-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/php/checks) itself
- Then see example of custom rule project [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/php-custom-rules)
- Overall documentation on custom rules for SonarPHP is [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+PHP)

And finally if you have any questions or feedback, you can write to sonarqube@googlegroups.com

Comment: Can you give me please simple example for php? Thank you!

Comment: Elena Vilchik gave you the path of a custom rule project. Look at this file, it's quite informative: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/master/php-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/php/checks/ForbiddenFunctionUseCheck.java